# Showing specific output data based on duplicate rows and null values [postgresql]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using the following SQL (with a union to two similar queries):

```
SELECT
    distinct a.source,
    a.p_id,
    a.name,
    b.prod_count,
    b.prod_amt,
    'Def' as prod_type
FROM
    dwh.attribution_product_count a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
SELECT
    distinct source,
    p_id,
    name,
    sum(acct_count) as prod_count,
    sum(acct_amt) as prod_amt
FROM
    dwh.prod_count
WHERE
    month = 3 AND
    default_banner_flag = 0 AND
    loan_flag = 3
GROUP BY
    source,
    name,
    p_id ) as b
        ON
        a.p_id = b.p_id
UNION
SELECT
    distinct a.source,
    a.p_id,
    a.name,
    b.prod_count,
    b.prod_amt,
    'Other' as prod_type
FROM
    dwh.attribution_product_count a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
SELECT
    distinct source,
    p_id,
    name,
    sum(acct_count) as prod_count,
    sum(acct_amt) as prod_amt
FROM
    dwh.prod_count
WHERE
    month = 3 AND
    default_banner_flag = 1 AND
    loan_flag = 3
GROUP BY
    source,
    name,
    p_id
ORDER BY
    name ) as b
        ON
        a.p_id = b.p_id
```

The output I'm getting looks like this:

[image]
Essentially since FakeName #2 has one row showing actual numbers (not null), I ONLY want FakeName #2 to show up. This means I also want the null row for FakeName #2. But, since FakeName #1 and #3 have 2 null rows, I don't need them to show. What type of SQL command (or edit to my query) can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if I read your query correctly, you can eliminate the need for a `UNION` by using `CASE` and `IN`. You also have a couple of bogus `DISTINCT`s in there (since you're using `GROUP BY` anyway). That gives:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.source,
    a.p_id,
    a.name,
    b.prod_count,
    b.prod_amt,
    Case When default_banner_flag = 0 Then 'Def' Else 'Other' End as prod_type
FROM
    dwh.attribution_product_count a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        source,
        p_id,
        name,
        default_banner_flag,
        sum(acct_count) as prod_count,
        sum(acct_amt) as prod_amt
    FROM
        dwh.prod_count
    WHERE
        month = 3 AND
        default_banner_flag in (0, 1) AND
        loan_flag = 3
    GROUP BY
        source,
        name,
        p_id,
        default_banner_flag
) as b
ON
a.p_id = b.p_id
```

However, what you actually want is information about those `p_id`s which have at least one row in `dwh.prod_count`, so I think you can change your whole query around to use that as the sub-select:

```
SELECT
    a.source,
    a.p_id,
    a.name,
    sum(acct_count) as prod_count,
    sum(acct_amt) as prod_amt,
    Case When default_banner_flag = 0 Then 'Def' Else 'Other' End as prod_type
FROM
    dwh.attribution_product_count a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dwh.prod_count b
    On a.p_id = b.p_id
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p_id
    FROM
        dwh.prod_count
    WHERE
        month = 3 AND
        default_banner_flag in (0, 1) AND
        loan_flag = 3
    ) as c
    ON a.p_id = c.p_id
WHERE
    month = 3 AND
    default_banner_flag in (0, 1) AND
    loan_flag = 3
```

(You could also rewrite this as a `WHERE p_id IN ( sub-select )` or with a little fiddling `WHERE EXISTS ( ... )`, but this seemed the easiest version to demonstrate.)

Note that I haven't actually tested any of these queries, but I think they're logically sound.